# Want to make public my AWS S3 bucket public?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, flutter

I want to make my aws bucket public, I have uploaded some images and now I want to access all using backend but object url not working in any case.

Already tried-

1. Make the bucket policy public.
2. Already 'Public access' enable.
3. Disable 'Block all public access'.

Upload using flutter app

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>13CF32E47FC7A79D</RequestId>
<HostId>
z5CK+xZJJwb15rP/JKyRXnw13XPvO/qwpdeXpcphehm3bE6Tl89qGN/+wiK3m+QcTA0/ESV+/uY=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Comment: How do you set the public policy? Please upload your policy.

Comment: {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1571703334970",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1571703328363",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How can I grant public read access to some objects in my Amazon S3 bucket?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/read-access-objects-s3-bucket/)

You need to make bucket public and add **Bucket Policy** into your bucket **Permissions** settings. Example:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AddPerm",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name-example/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Already done!  It is not working, Whenever I try to get object through Url it is not working. Getting only message 'Acess denied'.

Comment: I think you are doing something wrong. There is officially AWS guide. Could do you read this guide again?

Comment: Please, set bucket policy like on my example!