# Flutter S3 Upload AccessDenied

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, dart, amazon-s3

I try to upload the file to S3 but it say AccessDenied, can somebody help me

Here is POST method i have used with http package

var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", Uri.parse('https://'+bucket+'.s3-'+region+'.'+host));

```
request.headers.addAll({
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
});

request.fields['Content-Type']='image/'+typePost;
request.fields['acl']=acl;
request.fields['key']=key;
request.fields['policy']=policy.encode();
request.fields['x-amz-algorithm']='AWS4-HMAC-SHA256';
request.fields['x-amz-credential']=credential;
request.fields['x-amz-date']=longDate;
request.fields['x-amz-signature']=signature.toString();
request.fields['x-amz-security-token']=sessionToken;
request.fields['file']=filePath;
```

var send = await request.send();
send;

```
var sendData = await http.Response.fromStream(send);

if (sendData.statusCode==200) {
  if (kDebugMode) {
    print("Success to upload");
  }
}
else {
  if (kDebugMode) {
    print("Failed to upload");
    print(sendData.body);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58540994/want-to-make-public-my-aws-s3-bucket-public Relates to S3 bucket policy or access